# React-native animations in native thread

Tags: react-native

Looking at these two threads

1. [Github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3579)
2. [ProductPains](https://productpains.com/%E2%80%A6/offload-some-animations-from-js%E2%80%A6/)

it seems as animations are ported over to the native thread and performs them natively. Am I correct if I think that all the animations are done natively now or we should enable it manualy? If I am correct, is it production ready?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that you need to include `userNativeDriver:true` inside the animation configuration whenever you want the animation to offload from the js thread.

Example:

```
_animate = () => {
    Animated.timing(this.state.animValue, {
      toValue: 1,
      duration: 500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  };
```